# Unable to print binary tree node value

Tags: java, tree, depth-first-search

I was trying to print the value of binary tree nodes.
System.out.println("root.left"+root.left);

But console shows the output as:

root.leftTreeNode@5025a98f

Comment: Add a `toString()` implementation to your Node class to print out what you want to see in console.

Answer (score 0):

root.left is an object not an actual primitive type that can be printed, so it's just printing the pointer value and the class name TreeNode. You're looking for something like root.left.value or whatever is storing an actual printable value in the structure contained in root.left. Either that or implement a toString method to the class.